# Reltable in a dita map file doesn't give pdf output but gives html5 output

Tags: dita

If I have reltable in a dita map file, then if I create the html5 output, I get the output but when I set the output to be a PDF File, I don't get the output.

The reltable is useful for html5 content only.

Please confirm the same to me.

Regards

Deepak Bhatia

Answer (score 0):

There is a publishing parameter called "args.rellinks" which you should set to "all":
https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/parameters/parameters-base.html